# How to simulate a load test of 500tps using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter for testing my REST API. The API must handle around 100 tps load. I am using following hardware for generating load:

```
CPU - 8 Cores
RAM - 16 Gb
3.0 GHz Intel Xeon Platinum Processor
_JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xms1g -Xmx12g
```

Now I have single http GET request.
My JMeter configuration:

```
number of users - 10000
ramp up time -  100 seconds
```

The above configuration means 100 concurrent users per second, and that one request is equal to 1 trasaction per second.
Am I interpreting it correctly? 
Also, how should I plan to test my API for 500tps load?
My server runs out of memory if I increase the number of threads.

Comment: Scale Jmeter to thousands of users with few gigs of ram using plugin that i have developed https://github.com/nirmal-mewada/jmeter-loom

Answer (score 2):

The above configuration **doesn't mean 100 concurrent users per second**. It also **does not mean `one request is equal to 1 trasaction per second` whatever you mean by this**.

The above configuration means that

- JMeter will start 100 users each second
- The users will start execute the request **as fast as they can**
- Once virtual user finishes the request it will be shut down

The actual number of concurrent users and transactions per seconds depends on **your server response time**, i.e. if response time will be 1 second - you will have 100 transactions per second, if response time will be 2 seconds - you will have 50 transactions per second, if response time will be 0.5 seconds - you will have 200 transactions per second.

If your goal is to achieve 100 or 500 tps - I would recommend using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) and [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) combination. They can be put together using [feedback function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) so JMeter will automatically start new threads in order to reach/maintain the defined concurrency.

Both test elements can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)